# Why doesn't Dagger2 inject my Kotlin Android App?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger

I am currently learning how to inject into Android apps with Dagger 2. I wrote a very basic code, but it refuses to work. My goals is it to inject the MainActicity as it should be. It builds 
My code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

   @Inject lateinit var info: Info
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        AndroidInjection.inject(this)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        txt_view.text = info.textInformation
    }
}

class Info {val textInformation = "You are able to read this"    }
@Module
class InfoModule{
    @Provides
    fun info ():Info{
        return Info()
    }
}

class CustomApp : Application (),HasActivityInjector{

    @Inject
    lateinit var dispatchingAndroidInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity>

    override fun activityInjector(): AndroidInjector<Activity> {
        return dispatchingAndroidInjector
    }
}

@Component(modules = arrayOf(AndroidInjectionModule::class,
    ActivityModule::class))
interface ApplicationComponent{
    fun inject(application: CustomApp)
}

@Module
abstract class ActivityModule{
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = arrayOf(InfoModule::class))
    abstract fun contributeInfoActivityInjector():MainActivity
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that I forgot to add this code to the CustomApp class, and .CustomApp to the manifest file

```
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    initDi()
}

private fun initDi() {
    DaggerApplicationComponent.builder().build().inject(this)
}
```